# When reinstalling Windows XP, which option would you choose?

Tags: windows-xp, installation

When reinstalling Windows XP to replace an installation with a corrupted registry, I have two options.

1. Reformat the disk and start with a blank disk.
2. Leave the original filesystem intact, so I can recover the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about re-installing Windows (rather than just fixing/correcting the registry), I'd suggest backing up any files you will want to use again to some external storage (external HD, DVD, online backup, etc...) and then do a clean format and re-install. If you can't even get the current installation to boot, then either mount it as an external drive for a different OS, or use a Windows recovery boot disc (it's been a while since I've done this but there should be many such things out there).

Comment: How would you fix the registry of an XP machine?

Comment: @Moshe: I don't know, it's never happened to me. I suggest that you ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I ended up not deleting the original files. Then, I replaced the corrupted registry hive with the one from the new install. Problem solved.